# PrusaSlicer not making sense

Tags: prusaslicer

I'm using PrusaSlicer 2.3.1 on a custom delta.

I'm printing a basic 25x25 mm cubic shell for calibration purposes. It keeps setting the print speed to 20 mm/sec despite there being no speed specifically that low (well, except gaps, but these walls are presented as external perimeters in the post-slice viewer.)

I've also ensured the minimum printing speed (cooling section) is 30 mm/s, and set the 'slow down if print is below' to like 1 second but it refuses to change.

In fact, I just turned off all auto-cooling and the software didn't even require a re-slice! I jogged the position a hair which forces a reslice but the end result is the same.  This refusal to require a reslice has been showing up a lot lately, never had this kind of problem in the original Slic3r I've been using for years.

Comment: What is the question here? Your contribution reads more like a rant (especially the last sentence).

Comment: Yes, sorry about that subject line!  I've lost hair chasing this problem down and it looks like I have a software problem making it really hard to pin down. People in other forums opened my project file (.3mf) and couldn't find a problem and recreating it *consistently* has been really hard.  I'm in the process of crossing my fingers and re-installing.

Comment: So do you really have a specific *question* then that we can answer? Perhaps making a bug report with Prusa would be a better course of action.

Comment: Prusa would ask me to document how to duplicate the problem but I'm having problem duplicating *consistently*.  My question is:  why did Prusaslicer spit out gcode that prints my single-walled calibration

Comment: My question: 
To start off simply, if I have auto-cooling enabled and the minimum speed allowed is set to 30 mm/sec, and print speed is set to 30mm/sec, is there EVER a (normal) situation that would slow down my print to 20mm/sec,? Because that is what seems to be happening, if I understand them correctly.
At the moment I can't even recreate the problem, which is where my headaches started.  I sent a .3mf file to the Prusaslicer forum and it sliced fine on their computers.